# How to use VNC to connect to the Windows XP home edition

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, vnc, putty

I would like to remote into a computer on my network from another computer on my network. How do I do this using VNC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the other computer is running an SSH server, and the other computers firewall is set up to permit SSH traffic.

**Edit:**  Windows has a very, very good remote control protocol built in. To enable it go to your System Properties, Remote Settings and then select one of the two "Allow Connection" options.

From the other computer, you then start the Remote Desktop program and put in the details of the other computer, and bingo.

Comment: How do I enable this option on Windows XP Home. I have Remote Desktop on Windows 7 Home

Comment: @user - I don't think Windows Home has this feature. Because you're on XP Home, I'm going to have to move this over the Super User, because this is a site for dealing with server technologies. If you're on Windows Home, then you may very well need VNC as you mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: I've checked by Windows XP machine, and it comes equipped with Remote Desktop. How do I connect to another computer using this? What's the difference between remote desktop and VNC connections?